# Two textview one after another not usinge LinearLayout weight

Tags: android

I want to create view, which will contain two textView, each one to another (see the photo), not using LinearLayout weight (it's a bad for performance).

For now, I have a contraint, but my yellow text is always on the end. How to make one text each one to another (without putting one text under another) and not using Spannable or String (only in xml)?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/personalInfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/personalBonusPromoName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/personalInfoBlock"
        tools:text="Very long text very long text"
        tools:textColor="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/personalInfoBlock"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintS_toStartOf="@+id/personalBonusPromoName"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/personalBonusPromoAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/goldenyellow"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="1000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: remove LinearLayout which is not required if you are using ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstraintLayout, solution below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```